# check old login twitter

Tags: c#, twitter

The story of twitter api (that I did myself ) continues like this;

I click twitter button and I open a twitter popup in my user website,
and then it's received approval to allow the application (standard
procedure). I use "oAuth" for connection.
there is no problem until here
in my user website, when you want the 2nd access, after you click the
button, it has to accept the application again.
Can I make control automatically the people who were accepted  to the
system before and Can I control automatically accepting the
application and entry without opening "popup" ?

I mean if the users are accepted once, they should be accepted for
other entry to the system automatica

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the user's `access_token` (received from OAuth) in a session and make a process such that, if there's no `access_token` in the session, redirect to the popup window for authentication.

Comment: keep acces_token but when the user want to access in user other pc   if opened a session on twitter before i want it to check out automatically

Comment: what do you mean by checkout? but if the user logs in to twitter on other PC, that...twitter has to handle session management....